# How to increase the allocated disk space for the /home directory?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, user-space

How can I increment space for `/home`? My first `/boot` directory was 5 gigabytes and next I changed to 1 gigabyte. Now I'm confused because the change give me unallocated with size 5.02GiB. How can I add this unallocated 5.02GiB to `/home`?

[image: gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucise.png)]
*click to see full resolution*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to increase your /home partition.

- Create a Ubuntu Live USB and boot from it.
- Go to Gparted and turn off your swap partition. (Rightclick-->swap off)

  [image]
- Rightclick on swap partition-- > "**Resize/Move**"--> Move it to the Rightmost area.
- Right click on home partition (`/dev/sda6`) --> "**Resize/Move**" --> Increase its size by dragging it.
- Apply changes.

### Now you need to Correct the UUID entries in the `fstab` file.

(If you move your /boot partition)

Chroot to your original `/` partition and reinstall grub:

Execute the following commands in sequence.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt/boot
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub  
exit
```

Update the UUID entries in `fstab` file as given below:

Open another terminal and execute :

```
sudo blkid
```

Open one more terminal and execute :

```
sudo gedit /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Replace the UUID entries of `sda6` & `sda7` (& `sda8` if you move the boot partition too) with those of the output given from the `blkid` command.

Reboot.

Comment: thanks for your Answer.
but How can i get UUID ? and why I need boot live ubuntu via usb ?
I install it ubuntu on laptop .
no live

Comment: You need to be in a live session as you can't safely operate on the disk partitions while the system is in use. The `sudo blkid` command is the one that gives you the UUIDs for the partitions.

Comment: wow .Thanks man I try your solution it worked for me 
thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question. You can get the UUIDs by `sudo blkid` . You need to do this on a LIVE usb because you are editing Swap and /boot partition. Otherwise its like [Cutting off the branch one is sitting on](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JcWMh.jpg) ! .

Comment: I have some question I have 2 users, userA and userB then userA have 1G space and userB have 1G space so I need increment sapce userA to 4G How can I do this?

Comment: @Rayan_skofw if you have a new question, please [ask it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) separately. Remember to explain your partition setup clearly (tell us why each user only has a limited amount of disk space, are you using separate partitions for each home directory?)

Comment: You do *not* need to update `/etc/fstab` here as moving a partition does not change its UUID. You must only do that if you delete a partition to recreate it elsewhere or if you create an entirely new partition that needs to get mounted automatically at boot. Also, if you don't modify the `/boot` (or maybe also root `/`) partition, there's absolutely no need to reinstall GRUB. Even if you moved one of those, I am not sure it would be necessary in any case as long as the order and the UUIDs stay the same.